# Is there a way to return an Object from JavaScript in Java using Selenium JavascriptExecutor?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm facing a problem running a JavaScript file with Java, using Selenium I log in my application and run my JavaScript file with JavascriptExecutor, but I'm unable to receive a valid return from it, only null.

Here is the snippet from my code:

```
public static void runJavascriptFile(ChromeDriver driver) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start");
        Object js = driver.executeScript(TestHelper.getTextFromFile("demo-client/scripts/get-test.js"));
        System.out.println(js);
        System.out.println("End");

    }
```

My js file contains following content:

```
async function getPeople() {
    let response = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/", { method: "GET" })
    console.log("This is from my Javascript File from Java.")
    return response.status;
}
let result = await getPeople();
console.log("result", result);
```

Here I can see the return from JavaScript file in Chrome browser console, but in Java IDE I'm not able:
[BrowserConsoleXJavaConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmm5D.jpg)

If anyone knows a different approach that works, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to string instead :

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String fileContent = (String) jsExec.executeScript("some js code here to get the file content");
System.out.println(fileContent);
```

Comment: I just tried this approach now, but it also returned null.

Comment: you are using this in JS call `TestHelper.getTextFromFile("demo-client/scripts/get-test.js")`- this looks like reading simply a file. what exactly you wanna do ?

Comment: Exactly, it only read a file from it's location, if I remove this auxiliary method and use my complete code there I still receive null value, like below.
`String fileContent = (String) jsExec.executeScript("javascript code");`

I need to be able to get this JavaScript file return to my Java code, so I can see the output and log it later for each JavaScript file executed.